# Sharing Ethernet connection with Wifi and USB ethernet using systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd-networkd

**Context**: I am running raspbian 11 on a raspberry pi 4 and have connected a usb ethernet nic. My goal is to allow clients to connect to wifi (wlan0) or via the usb ethernet (eth1), then have the pi route all traffic through the main ethernet connection (eth0). This setup needs to be able to run when eth0 is not connected (obviously without internet).

**Problem**: I have all the interfaces configured, but wlan0 and eth1 do not get traffic routed to the eth0 internet connection.

Here is how I have configured systemd-networkd:

/etc/systemd/network/09-default.network:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[Bridge]
Priority=0

[DHCPv4]
ClientIdentifier=mac
```

/etc/systemd/network/10-wlan0.network:

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0
Type=wlan

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.8.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
IPMasquerade=yes

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=10
PoolSize=100
```

/etc/systemd/network/11-eth1.network:

```
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.10.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
IPForward=yes
IPMasquerade=yes

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=10
PoolSize=100
```

Comment: have you confirmed that your configuration is doing all the right things? e.g. `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is `1` and the appropriate nft/iptables rules are persent

Comment: doesn't systemd-networkd configure this for you?

Comment: Sure, but "have you confirmed" isn't asking *"what **should** systemd-networkd do for you"* it's more like asking *"did systemd-networkd do what you expect it to do for you"*

Comment: Are you willing to share how I can check those things? I admit my knowledge of network configuration is lacking.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the level of your abilities. you can use `sysctl` to get the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` value the `nft` command to check if the nft rules are in place